# Output an alert after prompt is confirmed

Tags: javascript

So for a class assignment I need to have a simple form with two inputs.
One for name and one for age.
After those two are entered, a prompt appears that asks for the users favorite color. That color is then applied to the pages background then a alert pops up saying: username + " your color was applied to the bg. You are " + userAge...

My problem is, I am able to do one of these things. but not the other at the same time.

So how to I get an alert to appear after the user clicks OK on the prompt?

```js
function getNameAge( userName, userAge ) {
  var nameAndAge = userName + " your favorite color was applied to the background. " + "You are " + userAge;
  return nameAndAge;
}

function getColor( favColor ) {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor;
   alert(nameAndAge)
}

//Need to put these two in one click of a button
document.getElementById( "submit" ).onclick = function(){
  getColor( prompt("Please enter your favorite color." ));
}

document.getElementById( "submit" ).onclick = function(){
  alert( getNameAge( 
    document.getElementById( "name" ).value,
    document.getElementById( "age" ).value 
  ));
}
```

```html
<form name="frmArea">
Please enter your Name and Age:<br>
Name: <input type="text" name="txtName" id="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="txtAge" id="age"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script src="../Homework 18/favColor.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait i got it, I had a two hour brain fart

```js
document.getElementById( "submit" ).onclick = function(){
  getColor( prompt("Please enter your favorite color." ));
  alert( getNameAge( 
    document.getElementById( "name" ).value,
    document.getElementById( "age" ).value 
  ));
}
```